# Evaluation of two Strings in java

Tags: java, string

I would like to know why the second `System.out.println` statement prints false and not true. I believe the strings would be cached and both s1 and s3 point to the same string object, then why would false be printed when both strings have same value.

```
 String s="hello";
 String s1="hello5";
 String s2="hello"+5;
 String s3="hello"+s.length();
 System.out.println(s1==s2);//prints true
 System.out.println(s1==s3); //I know equals method would print true
```

Comment: because they don't refer to the same object in the memory. equals would return true, because in value they are the same.

Comment: PS : For folks who are planning to close this question as a dup of *how do I compare Strings in Java*. I don't think that would be the right dup :)

Comment: Yes, but why s1==s2 prints true? I think that is what @Swanand is talking about.

Answer (score 4):

```
 String s2="hello"+5;
 String s3="hello"+s.length();
 System.out.println(s1==s2);//prints true
 System.out.println(s1==s3); //I know equals method would print true
```

the second SOP checks at runtime not at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler replaces `"hello" + 5` with "hello5" during compile time itself (which is valid because both are constants) where as call to `String#length()` is done at runtime (And hence the compiler cannot use "hello5" directly).

Byte code :

```
         0: ldc           #19                 // String hello ==> s
         2: astore_1
         3: ldc           #21                 // String hello5 ==> s1
         5: astore_2
         6: ldc           #21                 // String hello5 ===> s2 <==
         8: astore_3
         9: new           #23                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
        12: dup
        13: ldc           #19                 // String hello 
        15: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        18: aload_1
        19: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
        22: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        25: invokevirtual #38                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second print statement is false, because at runtime the two Strings s1 and s3 point to different locations of memory.

E.g. if we have two strings:

```
   String s1 = "Hi";
   String s2 = "Hi".trim();
   System.out.println(s1==s2); //Yields false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s3="hello"+s.length();
```

Computed at runtime, because until and unless the `length()` function isn't evaluated, it's value will remain unknown.

String Literal Pool has a major role to play in this.
s1 and s2 will refer to the same String in the string literal pool.

This will return false:

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = new String("hello");// creates new string in pool
```

Use of `equals()` is better when checking for equality in strings and objects. For objects you have to override `equals()` method,because by default `equals()` and `==` have same nature.